# Delete object or bucket in Amazon S3?

Tags: php, object, amazon-s3, bucket

I created a new amazon bucket called "photos". The bucket url is something like:

```
www.amazons3.salcaiser.com/photos
```

Now I upload subfolders  containing files, into that bucket for example

```
www.amazons3.salcaiser.com/photos/thumbs/file.jpg
```

My questions are, does `thumbs/` is assumed a new bucket or is it an object?

Then if I want to delete the entire `thumbs/` directory need I first to delete all files inside that or can I delete all in one time?

Comment: there are no folders in s3 you would delete all objects with the same prefix

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the case you are describing, "photos" is the **bucket**. S3 does not have sub-buckets or directories. Directories are simulated by using slashes in the object **key**. "thumbs/file.jpg" is an object key and "thumbs/" would be considered a key **prefix**.

Dagon's examples are good and use the older version 1.x of the AWS SDK for PHP. However, you can do this more easily with the newest [2.4.x version AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) which includes a helper method for deleting multiple objects.

```
<?php

// Include the SDK. This line depends on your installation method.
require 'aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'your-aws-access-key',
    'secret' => 'your-aws-secret-key',
));

// Delete the objects in the "photos" bucket with the a prefix of "thumbs/"
$s3->deleteMatchingObjects('photos', 'thumbs/');
```

Comment: this is quite awesome, do you know if deleteMatchingObjects() launchs multiple or single request to s3?

Comment: There is no possible way to do this without executing multiple requests. However, it does try to do as few as possible by using S3's [multi-object delete API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) under the hood.

Comment: @JeremyLindblom Is it possible to use this method and the key to delete all occurrences ? Ie. different prefixes but same filename. small/a.png , thumb/a.png , large/a.png ?

Comment: I think the regex param from the method signature will work. public function deleteMatchingObjects($bucket, $prefix = '', $regex = '', array $options = array()) , awesome.

Comment: dont know but i am using phpsdk-v3 and its not working anymore

Comment: $s3->deleteMatchingObjects('photos', 'thumbs/'); this function return any thing to identify deleted successfully execute?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Include s3.php file first in code

if (!class_exists('S3'))
            require_once('S3.php');
        //AWS access info
        if (!defined('awsAccessKey'))
            define('awsAccessKey', 'awsAccessKey');
        if (!defined('awsSecretKey'))
            define('awsSecretKey', 'awsSecretKey');
        //instantiate the class
        $s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

  if ($s3->deleteObject("bucketname", `filename`)) {
        echo 'deleted';
}
else
{
echo 'no file found';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

found some code snippets for  'directory' deletion - i did not write them:

PHP 5.3+:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$bucket = 'your-bucket';
$folder = 'folder/sub-folder/';

$s3->get_object_list($bucket, array(
    'prefix' => $folder
))->each(function($node, $i, $s3) {
    $s3->batch()->delete_object($bucket, $node);
}, array($s3));
$responses = $s3->batch()->send();

var_dump($responses->areOK());
```

Older PHP 5.2.x:

```
$s3 = new AmazonS3();


$bucket = 'your-bucket';
$folder = 'folder/sub-folder/';

$s3->get_object_list($bucket, array(
    'prefix' => $folder
))->each('construct_batch_delete', array($s3));

function construct_batch_delete($node, $i, &$s3)
{
    $s3->batch()->delete_object($bucket, $node);
}

$responses = $s3->batch()->send();

var_dump($responses->areOK());
```

Comment: thank you for the lovely piece of code! from the code above i can see i need to list and delete all by one the objects which are not subfolders ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in Yii as,

```
$aws = Yii::$app->awssdk->getAwsSdk();
$s3 = $aws->createS3();
$s3->deleteMatchingObjects('Bucket Name','object key');
```