# Error setting certificate verify locations when using Amazon S3 PHP sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the code to implement Amazon S3 delete object

```
    require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/aws.phar');

    $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
                'key' => S3_KEY,
                'secret' => S3_SECRET
    ));

    $s3->deleteMatchingObjects(S3_BUCKET, "abc.mp4");
```

The error message is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException' with message '[curl] 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /tmp/guzzle-cacert.pem CApath: none [url] https://testdomain.s3.amazonaws.com?prefix=abc.mp4' in phar:///home/in001/public_html/yoga/application/libraries/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php:359 Stack trace: #0 phar:///home/in001/public_html/yoga/application/libraries/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(292): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->isCurlException(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #1 phar:///home/in001/public_html/yoga/application/libraries/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(257): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processResponse(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request), Object(Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlHandle), Array) #2 phar:///home/in001/public_html/yoga/application/libraries/aws.phar/Guzzle/Http/Curl/CurlMulti.php(240): Guzzle\Http\Curl\CurlMulti->processMessages() #3 phar:///home/in001/public_html/yo in phar:///home/in001/public_html/yoga/application/libraries/aws.phar/Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php on line 258
```

I have followed the example here:

[Delete object or bucket in Amazon S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346308/delete-object-or-bucket-in-amazon-s3)

and logged all parameter is correct, any idea of how to fix it?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the .phar , download the zip file

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases

and require like this:

```
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/aws/aws-autoloader.php');
```

fixed the problem